# Extract values from dictionaries as records in dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe which has several columns with values as dictionaries.
These columns also contain some None (not sure if it's a string or just missing values).

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[{0: 300}, {0: 157}, {0: 456}],[{0: 298}, None, {0: 498}],[None, None, {0: 987}]],   columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

All dictionaries have key = 0, values = number from 100 to 10000.

I need to loop through all columns and rows and extract only the value. Preferably, i will overwrite the columns with only the values

So, end result should look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[300, 157, 456],[298, None, 498],[None, None, 987]],   columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

The number is actually an ID which I will use later on for a "vlookup" into another dataframe.

I tried with lambda functions:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: x.values() if x is not None else x)
```

I did manage to extract the values. Issue is the type of these values is recognized as a dictionary value (they look like this when i print them: (300)).

I need them as integers. I tried chaining an astype(int) but i do get an error (something like, you can't do that on a dictionary's value)
Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example _as text_ and a clear expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) for processing all columns with get first values of dict values:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: list(x.values())[0] if isinstance(x, dict) else x)
print (df)
    col1   col2  col3
0  300.0  157.0   456
1  298.0    NaN   498
2    NaN    NaN   987
```

If need integers convert values to [`Int64`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html):

```
df = (df.applymap(lambda x: list(x.values())[0] if isinstance(x, dict) else x)
       .astype('Int64'))
print (df)
   col1  col2  col3
0   300   157   456
1   298  <NA>   498
2  <NA>  <NA>   987
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: @santee - Answer was edited.

Comment: Nevermind. You solution works. I was just looping through my entire dataframe (which has also columns of other types). I restricted to the ones with dictionaries, and now works. Thank you